# Angular Json Property Undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm getting a Json object which contains other json object as properties .

```
[
    {
     "prop": "\{"p" : "1\"}"
    }
]
```

I'm parsing it this way :

```
 this.Auth.process().subscribe((x: any[]) => {

        console.log(JSON.parse(x[0].prop)); /// Works

         console.log('res: ' + JSON.parse(x[0].prop).p); /// Undefined.
        });
```

when i try to retreive the json property i get undefined as result .

Comment: try `JSON.parse(x)[0].prop` instead (decode the whole string first, then access the property) (NOTE: your JSON is not valid)

Comment: Your example JSON is invalid.

Comment: @Kaddath yes json was manually typed . but your solution worked tho ty .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse(x[0].prop).p` is undefined because value of `x[0].prop` is string and not a JSON.

You can parse `x[0]` first and then fetch the value of p from the derived object -

```
JSON.parse(x)[0].prop
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. Try removing the quotes like this example.

```
[
    {
     "prop": {"p" : "1"}
    }
]
```